# Detecting gestures that begin outside of the application frame when running on iPad?

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad

Is it possible to detect swipe gestures that begin in the black "frame" that iOS puts around iPhone apps when they're running on an iPad at 1x?

My app has a navigation drawer that slides out from the left side of the screen. When the user is running the app on an iPad, it's really easy to start the swipe that is supposed to open the drawer in the black border--outside of the application frame. When this happens, the swipe isn't detected.

My gut tells me that this part of the screen just doesn't exist from my app's point of view, but I'd like to know that for sure. This one is tough to Google for...

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: This is an odd problem, but I'll try to give some ideas. You could try the jquery mobile swipe event. http://api.jquerymobile.com/swipe/ Also the jquery touchswipe plugin might work. http://www.netcu.de/jquery-touchwipe-iphone-ipad-library If those don't work I would think that Safari might not accept touches that start outside the screen.

Comment: Hey David, thanks for the reply. This is actually a native app, though, not a web app running in Safari.

Answer (score 0):

No the gestures are restricted to the app itself, and it is OS dependent. We cannot handle the gestures outside the application.

Comment: Thanks, Ashish. Do you have a source document you could point me to?